# Log4j displaying incorrect logging levels

Tags: java, log4j

My logger seems to be working quite nicely, but recently it's been displaying `DEBUG` messages. I'm not completely sure why, because I've not changed anything.

This is the contents of my `log4j.properties` file:

```
# Set root logger level to appropriate level and its appender to A1, R
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, A1, R
# A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# A1 uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p [%c] %m%n

# R is set to be a rolling log file appender
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=${catalina.home}/logs/evepromote.log

# R also uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p [%c] %m%n
```

I only want to display `INFO` messages, and I thought I had done that with `log4j.rootLogger`. Can anyone see a reason why `DEBUG` messages are being displayed?

**EDIT**

First `DEBUG` line is from `spring`, which is.. confusing really. I've been using `Spring` from the start and it't not done this before:

```
2014-01-08 10:16:26,742 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment] Initializing new StandardServletEnvironment
```

**Output from Log4j Initialisation**

```
log4j: Using URL [file:/C:/IntelliJIdea/IntelliJIdea/system/tomcat/Unnamed_EvePromote/work/Catalina/localhost/evepromote/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Preferred configurator class: org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator
log4j: System property is :null
log4j: Standard DocumentBuilderFactory search succeded.
log4j: DocumentBuilderFactory is:    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
log4j: debug attribute= "null".
log4j: Ignoring debug attribute.
log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Level value for root is  [debug].
log4j: root level set to DEBUG
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender]
log4j: Setting property [target] to [System.out].
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d %-5p [%c] %m%n].
log4j: Adding appender named [console] to category [root].
```

What's really jumping out at me here is the fact that it's looking for a `.xml` file by default, when I have a `.properties` file.

Comment: Add `-Dlog4j.debug=true` to the server's startup. This will make log4j print debugging information to stdout.

Comment: But I want to remove debugging information?

Comment: I meant, it will make log4j print debugging information about *itself*: how log4j reads the configuration, and what decisions log4j makes throughout its own operation.

Comment: Wow, that's really given some insight. I'll edit the output into my question. @Isaac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log4J, by default, will look for a `log4j.xml` file first, and only if it can't find it - will look for `log4j.properties`. You can override this by setting the `log4j.configuration` system property to point at the exact configuration file you're interested in.

Comment: I solved the issue by using a `log4j.xml` file. While this isn't the exact fix you suggest, it's the same principle that lead me to my conclusion. Thankyou!

Comment: The `XML` format is actually preferred, as it enables features that aren't available in the Properties format. I'd of course advise you to convert your file to XML format... but not many people welcome change. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly because some 3rd party library you load up changed the global/logger level settings to enable DEBUG messages.

Check the first line of DEBUG information to see where it's initiated may give you some idea of which library is causing that; otherwise, try check if there is any newly added libraries/dependencies in your project.

Comment: Edited in my first line. It is from `spring` so I'm not sure that is the root cause..